# xpath request to select elements that appears exactly two times

Tags: xml, database, xpath

I'm facing a difficult request that i can't resolve.

So for example this is our xml database:

```
<A>
   <B>
   ...
   </B>

   <C>
   ...
   </C>

   <B>
   ...
   </B>

</A>
```

**The Question is** : what are the B child element of the element A that appears exactly two times.in our example the element B sould be the anwser.

**but** there is a restriction :we can't use count() or agregation function like min , max ....

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: So you mean that if `B` node appears 3 times, it should not be fetched? Also explain what *"something similar"* means

Comment: what do you mean by *we can't use count() or something similar.*? what are you allowed to use?

Comment: yes , i mean exactly 2 times ;no more , no less, i thought for following-sibling but it's not clear.

Comment: @hotfix i mean no agregation function like min max count .....

Comment: i have an idea but i don't know if it is good enough.so i ask for B in position one and ask if there is B in position two and no B in position 3.something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i get a solution to my problem without using agregate function.

so the XPath request is:

: `//A[B[1] and B[2] and not (B[3])]`

So we ask for elemnt A that have child B at position 1 and child B at position 2 and don't have child at position 3.